# build should fail if code coverage Report Percenatge is less

Tags: phpunit, phing

I have written a build.xml for generating Reports through phing.

I have added below command in build.xml to generate code coverage Report ::

```
<exec command="phpunit  --coverage-html ./code_Coverage_Report codecoverage_test/CodeCoverage.php "/>
```

Now i wanted to add a check in build.xml that if my code coverage Report percentage is less than 85% then the build should automatically fail.

Comment: Is this question in any way related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543641/stop-phing-deployment-if-code-coverage-is-below-85 ?

Comment: @Sven: Yes it seems the scenario and problems are similar

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with PHPUnit. There was a pull request to implement what you want, but it was rejected.

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/2402

Answer (score 0):

Although not directly possible with PHPUnit, there are alternative open-source packages that will let you do the same such as https://github.com/richardregeer/phpunit-coverage-check