# Stop phing deployment if code coverage is below 85%

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, phing

Am using a phing to deploy my php code but we need to add a condition to stop the deployment if any of the PHP Unit test cases fails or code coverage is less than 85%

We were able to add the PHP Unit test case condition by adding following code in built.xml

```
<phpunit  haltonerror="true" haltonfailure="true" printsummary="true">
</phpunit>
```

Now i need to test for the code coverage percentage, Please let me know how can i do that?

Comment: Is this in any way related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537272/build-should-fail-if-code-coverage-report-percenatge-is-less

Comment: @sven : Yes this seems to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the code coverage Percentage you can use clover Report, which will generate xml file.

From the xml file you can read the **Statements** and **coveredstatements** which will constitute you Total percentage

Clover Report can be generated using following command:

```
phpunit  --coverage-html ./code_Coverage_Report --coverage-clover ./cloverReport.xml codecoverage_test/CodeCoverage.php
```

**--coverage-html**: will generate the report in HTML format

**./code_Coveerage_Report**: will create a folder and the coverage clover report will be generate inside that folder

**--coverage-clover**: will generate a clover report

**./cloverReport.xml**: will generate an xml file for clover report

**codecoverage_test/CodeCoverage.php**: The file for which i need to generate coverage report

Answer (score 0):

With Phing's own PHPunit task being used, you could potentially use CoverageThresholdTask (http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apcs05.html)